# How to get an XML file from two input XML files with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files consisting of a list of TEI elements basically. One has the overall form I want to have in my output file with one exception: It doesn't have a sepcific attribute in the TEI-tags. The other file has these attributes.

The structure of the first file (abbreviated):

```
<root>
   <TEI>
      <teiHeader>
         <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt/></fileDesc></teiHeader>
   <TEI>
      <teiHeader>
         <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt/></fileDesc></teiHeader>
   <TEI>
      <teiHeader>
         <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt/></fileDesc></teiHeader>
   </TEI>

</root>
```

There are more child elements in every TEI-element of course which I need in my output file.

The structure of the second file (abbreviated):

```
<root>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
     xml:id="dhd_102">
   <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt/></fileDesc></teiHeader>
</TEI>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
     xml:id="dhd_103">
   <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt/></fileDesc></teiHeader>
</TEI>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
     xml:id="dhd_104">
   <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt/></fileDesc></teiHeader>
</TEI>
</root>
```

The second file has the attributes xmlns and xml:id that I need in the TEI-tags of the output file.

How can I define the two input files in my XSLT-file?

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute, it's a namespace declaration.  You can add it to your XML without needing to copy it from another document (provided it's always the same one, as it is in your example). As for the `xml:id`s, it's not clear what ties a TEI element in one document to a TEI element in the other one - is it just the position? Note that XSLT can generate unique id values on its own - so perhaps again you do not need to copy them from another document.

Comment: P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: You haven't said anything about how you want to combine the content of the two files. Concatenate them end to end? Combine matching entries? Please show a complete working example with specimen input and output. Please also indicate what you tried and how it failed - where did you get stuck?